# Postgres ERROR: could not open file for reading: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql

Computer: Mac OS X, version 10.8
Database: Postgres

Trying to import csv file into postgres.

```
pg> copy items_ordered from '/users/darchcruise/desktop/items_ordered.csv' with CSV;
ERROR:  could not open file "/users/darchcruise/desktop/items_ordered.csv" for reading: Permission denied
```

Then I tried

```
$> chown postgres /users/darchcruise/desktop/items_ordered.csv
chown: /users/darchcruise/desktop/items_ordered.csv: Operation not permitted
```

Lastly, I tried

```
$> ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 darchcruise  staff      1016 Oct 18 21:04 items_ordered.csv
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The `postges` server does not have read access in the directory where the file is stored. You must be root to change the user:group to `postgres`. (the `postgres` users must have read access on all directories above where the file is located [or all directories must be world-readable with the `x` execute bit set -- which governs "descend into" for directories]) If your `/tmp` is on `tmpfs`, `/tmp` won't work. Alternative, create a dedicated directory for `postgres` to read from, e.g. as root `mkdir -p /usr/local/postgres` and `chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/postgres` and put the file there

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
chmod a+rX /users/darchcruise/ /users/darchcruise/desktop /users/darchcruise/desktop/items_ordered.csv
```

This will change access rights for your folder. Note that everyone will be able to read your file.
You can't use chown being a user without administrative rights.
Also consider learning [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) to ease creation of shared files.

Comment: Hi, a little one liner that would do this task for you:
a=`pwd`;NumOfSlashes=$((`echo $a | sed 's/[^/]//g' | wc -c` - 1 )); for ((i=1;i<=$NumOfSlashes;i++)); do chmod a+rX $a; a=`dirname $a`;done;

Answer (score 158):

Assuming the `psql` command-line tool, you may use `\copy` instead of `copy`.

`\copy` opens the file and feeds the contents to the server, whereas `copy` tells the server the open the file itself and read it, which may be problematic permission-wise, or even impossible if client and server run on different machines with no file sharing in-between.

Under the hood, `\copy` is implemented as `COPY FROM stdin` and accepts the same options than the server-side `COPY`.

Comment: I wish I could mark this answer as useful every time I inevitably forget the `\\` and end up back here. Please accept my sincere thanks in-stead.

Comment: Yeah, this should be the accepted answer.  @J.M.Janzen, you can favorite the thread by clicking the star next to the question.

Answer (score 93):

Copy the CSV file to /tmp

For me this solved the issue.

Answer (score 24):

**Copy your CSV file into the /tmp folder**

Files named in a COPY command are read or written directly by the server, not by the client application. Therefore, they must reside on or be accessible to the database server machine, not the client. They must be accessible to and readable or writable by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as), not the client. COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to access.

Comment: Elegant. No permission change. No fear. No hassle.

Comment: What do you mean by "COPY naming a file"?

Answer (score 5):

I had the issue when I was trying to export data from a remote server into the local disk. I hadn't realised that SQL `copy` actually is executed on the server and that it tries to write to a server folder. Instead the correct thing to do was to use `\copy` which is the psql command and it writes to the local file system as I expected. http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFjNrYsE4Za_KWzmfgN1_-MG7GTw_vpMRxPk=OEjAiLqLskxdA@mail.gmail.com

Perhaps that might be useful to someone else too.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this, if you have pgAdmin and are comfortable using the GUI is to go the table in the schema and right click on the table you wish to import the file to and select "Import" browse your computer for the file, select the type your file is, the columns you want the data to be imputed into, and then select import.

That was done using pgAdmin III and the 9.4 version of PostgreSQL.

This still works for pgAdmin IV and PostgreSQL 16.

Comment: This option no longer exists on pgAdmin III

Comment: This worked like a charm. By far the easiest way to accomplish the objective.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the same issue with a recursive chown on the parent folder:

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /home/my_user/export_folder
```

(my export being in `/home/my_user/export_folder/export_1.csv`)

Answer (score 3):

for macbook first i opened terminal then type

```
open /tmp
```

or in finder directory you directly enter command+shift+g then type /tmp in go to the folder.

it opens temp folder in finder. then i paste copied csv file into this folder.then again i go to postgres terminal and typed below command and then it is copied my csv data into db table

```
\copy recharge_operator FROM '/private/tmp/operator.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Comment: Why does this work? and does it mean all the CSV files we want to import has to be copied into this folder from now on?

Answer (score 2):

You must grant the `pg_read_server_files` permission to the user if you are not using `postgres` `superuser`.

Example:

```
GRANT pg_read_server_files TO my_user WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Comment: Executing this gave me `ERROR:  role "pg_read_server_files" does not exist`

Answer (score 2):

```
COPY your table (Name, Latitude, Longitude) FROM 'C:\Temp\your file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Use `c:\Temp\"Your File"\`.

Comment: This solution throws the same error for me. 
``` enceladus=# COPY master_plan
enceladus-# FROM 'C:\Windows\Temp\master_plan.csv'
enceladus-# WITH DELIMITER ',' HEADER CSV;
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Windows\Temp\master_plan.csv" for reading: Pe
rmission denied

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to simply to add sudo (or run as root) for the chown command:

sudo chown postgres /users/darchcruise/desktop/items_ordered.csv

Answer (score 1):

I just copied the source csv file to another folder in which you have more permissions (C:/temp), and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac, did the following

open /tmp from terminal

/tmp folder opens in finder

Manually copied .csv data file to /tmp

Run command from query tool.
COPY tableName FROM '/private/tmp/employee.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Answer (score 0):

just in case you're facing this problem under windows 10 , add the group of users  "youcomputer\Users" on the security Tab and grant it full control , that solved my issue

Comment: Downvote, because it gives me: `"MYCOMPUTERNAME\Users" could not be found`. In the end, this is not the right advice (anymore?). You need to use the pgAdmin import menu instead. 

For "how", see [Data Will not import into PG Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153045/data-will-not-import-into-pg-admin/67164155#67164155).

For "why", see [Providing postgres windows system permission for copy (windows 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22598261/11154841).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but was using `psycopg2` to communicate with PostgreSQL. I fixed the permission issues by using the functions `copy_from` and `copy_expert` that will open the file on the client side as the user running the python script and feed the data to the database over `STDIN`.

Refer to [this link](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is only for Linux Beginners.**

Assuming initially the DB user didn't have file/folder(directory) permission on the client side.

> Let's constrain ourselves to the following:

User: `postgres`

Purpose: You wanted to (write to / read from) a specific folder

Tool: `psql`

Connected to a specific database: `YES`

FILE_PATH: `/home/user/training/sql/csv_example.csv`

Query: `\copy (SELECT * FROM table_name TO FILE_PATH, DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

Actual Results: After running the query you got an error : `Permission Denied`

Expected Results: `COPY COUNT_OF_ROWS_COPIED`

### Here are the steps I'd follow to try and resolve it.

1. Confirm the FILE_PATH permissions on your File system.

Inside a terminal to view the permissions for a file/folder you need to long list them by entering the command `ls -l`.

The output has a section that shows sth like this -> `drwxrwxr-x`
Which is interpreted in the following way:

TYPE | OWNER RIGHTS | GROUP RIGHTS | USER RIGHTS

`rwx` (r: Read, W: Write, X: Execute)

TYPE (1 Char) = d: directory, -: file

OWNER RIGHTS (3 Chars after TYPE)

GROUP RIGHTS (3 Chars after OWNER)

USER RIGHTS (3 Chars after GROUP)

2. If permissions are not enough (Ensure that a user can at least enter all folders in the path you wanted path) - `x`.

This means for FILE_PATH, All the directories (home , user, training, sql) should have at least an `x` in the USER RIGHTS.

3. Change permissions for all parent folders that you need to enter to have a `x`. You can use `chmod rights_you_want parent_folder`

Assuming `/training/` didn't have an execute permission.

I'd go the user folder and enter `chmod a+x training`

4. Change the destination folder/directory to have a `w` if you want to write to it. or at least a `r` if you want to read from it

Assuming `/sql` didn't have a write permission.

I would now `chmod a+w sql`

5. Restart the postgresql server `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`
6. Try again.

This would most probably help you now get a successful expected result.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can fix this by giving the `postgres` user read/write/execute permissions on the target directory. Eg:

```
setfacl -m u:postgres:rwx /home/hi
```

Comment: Make sure the directory you choose is not on `tmpfs`. (many distros now put `/tmp` on `tmpfs`). Reason, you cannot set acl's on `tmpfs`.

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this for a couple of hours. If you're a Windows user, try moving your file to 'C:\Users\Public'.

Answer (score -3):

May be You are using pgadmin by connecting remote host then U are trying to update there from your system but it searches for that file in remote system's file system... its the error wat I faced May be its also for u check it

Comment: This one is actually true, but could be more explainable. I had to copy file to the server to be able to load it in pgAdmin's console.