# How to export Postgres resultset as CSV from remote db connection to local machine?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, copy

I'm working on exporting resultset data from remote **PostgresQL DB** to my local machine using **Psycopg2**.

I have **SQL queries** that export the resultset into a CSV file. But those files are going to be created in the remote machine path where the DB is hosted. I'm using **psycpog2** to connect to the remote database using python.

As far as I understand we can run command `psql` to export the CSV file from terminal as mentioned in [How to insert CSV data into PostgreSQL database (remote database )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353997/how-to-insert-csv-data-into-postgresql-database-remote-database).

But how do I do the same thing using `Psycopg2 python`. Is there any way other than `os.system('psql ... .. ..')` to export CSV from remote db connection to my local using **python**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `copy_to` or `copy_expert` from the cursor class.  http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

```
import sys
import psycopg2

db = psycopg2.connect("")

with db.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.copy_expert(
        """copy (select * from pg_timezone_names) to stdout with csv header""",
        file=sys.stdout.buffer,
        size=256*1024
    )
```

To send data to a file instead of stdout:

```
import psycopg2

db = psycopg2.connect("")

with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    with db.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.copy_expert(
            """copy (select * from pg_timezone_names) to stdout with csv header""",
            file=f,
            size=256*1024
        )
```

Comment: What would the file name be when it is created on client machine?

Comment: This example (thanks @Tometzky) is just sending the data to stdout.  You could create any file you like and use that instead of sys.stdout.buffer.  I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Or just redirect output to a file with `program.py > filename.csv`.