# How to load a CSV file to PythonAnywhere

Tags: postgresql, pythonanywhere

I am using PythonAnywhere to practice loading csv file into postgre table.

I download file to the local C:\Users\YXFU\Desktop from https://www.pg4e.com/tools/sql/library.csv?PHPSESSID=3b1ad20ab2a59efb32411ec93d1906ca%22.,  and then I wrote query-

```
\copy track_raw(title, album, album_id, count, rating, len) FROM 'library.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV.
```

the result always return to be"`library.csv: No such file or directory`"

I just want to know how can I load an outside file to PythonAnywhere, and then I can work on it. thanks

Comment: Best guess is you are not running `psql` in the `C:\Users\YXFU\Desktop` directory. In that case you need to supply the complete path to the file.

Comment: Since the postgres machine is remote from where your console is running, you should use one of the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353997/how-to-insert-csv-data-into-postgresql-database-remote-database