# How to COPY CSV as JSON fields

Tags: postgresql, csv, jsonb

Is there a way to COPY the CSV file data directly into a JSON or JSONb array?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    info jSONb -- or JSON
);
COPY mytable(info) FROM '/tmp/myfile.csv' HEADER csv;
```

NOTE: each CSV line is mapped to a JSON array. It is a normal CSV.

---

Normal CSV (no JSON-embeded)...  `/tmp/myfile.csv` =

```
a,b,c
100,Mum,Dad
200,Hello,Bye
```

The correct COPY command must be equivalent to the usual copy bellow.

### Usual COPY (ugly but works fine)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 (
  a int, b text, c text
);
COPY temp1(a,b,c) FROM '/tmp/myfile.csv' HEADER csv;

INSERT INTO mytable(info) SELECT json_build_array(a,b,c) FROM temp1;
```

It **is ugly** because:

- need the *a priory* knowledge about fields, and a previous `CREATE TABLE` with it.
- for "big data" need a big temporary table, so lost CPU, disk and my time — the table `mytable` have CHECKs and UNIQUEs constraints for each line.
- ... Needs more than 1 SQL command.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824165/converting-a-csv-file-to-json-using-c-sharp

Comment: Show us the content of the file. But if it contains valid [JSON literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-KEYS-ELEMENTS) then this should work. What happened when you tried?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. Well, it works, but not in an elegant way (I am using "big data"), needs some steps and a temporary table... I edited, see example.

Comment: Thanks @JimMoore, yes, using an external program we can do anything... My question is about "how to" with PostgreSQL 9.6+.

Comment: You can avoid insert into table using file_fdw foreign data wrapper and read data directly from the file. Although it still requires previous knowledge of columns.

Comment: @JosMac, I think it is will be a good answer!  The "temporary table" is the big problem... Elegancy and the [*a priory* knowledge](http://frictionlessdata.io/guides/json-table-schema/) I can overlook ;-)

Comment: here is an example - http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/file_fdw-extension-small-hints/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Perfect solution!

Not need to know all the CSV columns, only extract what you know.

Use at SQL `CREATE EXTENSION PLpythonU;`: if the command produce an error like *"could not open extension control file ... No such file"* you need to install pg-py extra-packages. In standard UBUNTU (16 LTS) is simple, `apt install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython`.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_csvfile(
  file text,
  delim_char char(1) = ',',
  quote_char char(1) = '"')
returns setof text[] stable language plpythonu as $$
  import csv
  return csv.reader(
     open(file, 'rb'),
     quotechar=quote_char,
     delimiter=delim_char,
     skipinitialspace=True,
     escapechar='\\'
  )
$$;

INSERT INTO mytable(info)
  SELECT jsonb_build_array(c[1],c[2],c[3]) 
  FROM get_csvfile('/tmp/myfile1.csv') c;
```

The *split_csv()* function was [defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010608/287948). The `csv.reader` **is very reliable** (!).

Not tested for big-big CSV... But expected Python do job.

---

### PostgreSQL workaround

It is not a perfect solution, but it solves the main problem, that is the

> ... big temporary table, so lost CPU, disk and my time"...

This is the way we do it, a workaround with `file_fdw`!

1. Adopt your conventions to avoid file-copy and file-permission confusions... The standard file path for a CSV. Example: `/tmp/pg_myPrj_file.csv`
2. Initialise your database or SQL script with the magic extension,

```sql
   CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
   CREATE SERVER files FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;
```

3. For each CSV file, `myNewData.csv`,

   3.1. make a symbolic link (or `scp` remote copy) for your new file `ln -sf $PWD/myNewData.csv /tmp/pg_socKer_file.csv`

   3.2. configure the *file_fdw* for your new table (suppose `mytable`).

```sql
   CREATE FOREIGN TABLE temp1 (a int, b text, c text) 
   SERVER files OPTIONS ( 
     filename '/tmp/pg_socKer_file.csv', 
       format 'csv', 
       header 'true'
   );
```

PS: after running SQL script with `psql`, when having some permission problem, change owner of the link by `sudo chown -h postgres:postgres /tmp/pg_socKer_file.csv`.

3.3. use the *file_fdw* table as source (suppose populating `mytable`).

```
 INSERT INTO mytable(info)
 SELECT json_build_array(a,b,c) FROM temp1;
```

---

Thanks to @JosMac (and [his tutorial](http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/file_fdw-extension-small-hints/))!

---

**NOTE:** if there is a STDIN way to do it (exists??), will be easy, avoiding permission problems and use of absolute paths.  See [this answer/discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464904/287948).

Comment: For file permissions by ACL, see [this solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336675/130402)

Comment: Or just delimit the CSV with characters that exist neither in JSON or CSV... http://adpgtech.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/importing-json-data.html

Comment: Hi @DanielCull, good workaround. About the main problem, performance (CPU-time and memory costs), the only solution is `FOREIGN TABLE`. About other context or condictions, yes is possible to use the `csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';`, in a internal procedures, but not as *public data-interchange* (eg. see W3C's standards for semantic CSV or http://frictionlessdata.io interchange standards).

Comment: thank it works but your forgot to alias c "FROM get_csvfile('/tmp/myfile1.csv') c"

Comment: Hi @bormat, please edit (!) directally the text of the answer, it is a Wiki

Comment: that's right. I am not used to editing the post where I am not the author.

Comment: Sorry @bormat, you added "2 characters in body" correcting it (!)... I am deleting these comments.