# Postgresql - Regex split csv line with potentials quotes

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.4

I would like to split a column that represent a csv line in postgres. Fields in this text line are delimited by pipe, sometime they are enclosed by quote and sometime not. In addition we can have escaped chars.

```
field1|"field2"|field3|"22 \" lcd \| screen "
```

Is there a regex to split this column (i.e. using regexp_split_to_array(....)? )

Comment: `string_to_array(.., '|')` should work just fine

Comment: sorry for not being explicit, from field1|"field2"|field3|"22 \" lcd \| screen " i would obtain
field1
field2
field3
22 " lcd | screen

Comment: http://rextester.com/MXQPE34954

Answer (score 1):

Not about regexp but it works

```
create or replace function split_csv(
  line text,
  delim_char char(1) = ',',
  quote_char char(1) = '"')
returns setof text[] immutable language plpythonu as $$
  import csv
  return csv.reader(line.splitlines(), quotechar=quote_char, delimiter=delim_char, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='\\')
$$;

select *, x[4] from split_csv('field1|"field2"|field3|"22 \" lcd \| screen "'||E'\n'||'a|b', delim_char := '|') as x;
```

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════╗
║                      x                       │         x          ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════╣
║ {field1,field2,field3,"22 \" lcd | screen "} │ 22 " lcd | screen  ║
║ {a,b}                                        │ ░░░░               ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╧════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Hi, what kind of additional setup requires this solutions? Should I only add python postgres extension or do I need to install specific csv module?

Comment: @RobertoG. Honestly I am not sure. It works "out of the box" here (Linux+PostgreSQL+Python). Just try.

Comment: @RobertoG. BTW I was sleepy, sorry. Function simplified, more complex example added. Good luck.

Comment: For direct use (get CSV from filesystem!)  replace `line.splitlines()` by `open(line, 'rb')` and use a filename as input, eg. `/tmp/test.csv` . In general pg-server can read  only from `/tmp`.