# array function returning empty

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, plpython

The aim here is to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010608/287948) to return array instead of *setof*   datatype.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION split_csvline(
  line text,                 -- the input CSV string
  delim_char char(1) = ',',  -- can be also E'\t', ';', '|', etc.
  quote_char char(1) = '"'   -- field quotation
) RETURNS  text[] AS $f$
  import csv
  row = csv.reader(
      [line], 
      quotechar=quote_char, 
      delimiter=delim_char, 
      skipinitialspace=True, 
      escapechar='\\'
  )
  next(row)
$f$ IMMUTABLE language PLpythonU;

SELECT split_csvline('a,b');  -- empty!
```

---

EDIT

### Notes

It is a question about "using Python with PostgreSQL".

I am using *PLpythonU* because the staff use Python and because CSV is complex and need **reliable** (years of test) algorithm.

Not need a workaround, because a simple workaround is in use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION split_csv_line(
  text, char(1) DEFAULT ',', char(1) DEFAULT '"'
) RETURNS text[] AS $f$
  SELECT x FROM split_csv($1,$2,$3) x LIMIT 1;
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: why not using `select regexp_split_to_array('a,b',',');`?

Comment: @BenH, CSV is complex, see [this regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18147076/287948), perhaps using `regexp_matches()` ...

Comment: i know that csv is complex, but then you should consider a far better sample than `'a,b'`

Comment: You didn't use a `return` statement. IMHO *almost* all procedural language requires that if you want to return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv.reader` function returns a `reader` object. `next` is a `reader` object method:

```
create or replace function split_csvline(
    _line text,
    _delim_char char(1) = ',',  
    _quote_char char(1) = '"'
) returns  text[] as $f$
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(
        [_line], 
        quotechar = _quote_char, 
        delimiter = _delim_char, 
        skipinitialspace = True, 
        escapechar = '\\'
    )
    return reader.next()
$f$ immutable language plpythonu;

select split_csvline('a,b');
 split_csvline 
---------------
 {a,b}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_csvline(
   line text,                 -- the input CSV string
   delim_char char(1) = ',',  -- can be also E'\t', ';', '|', etc.
   quote_char char(1) = '"',  -- field quotation
   OUT result text[]
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   i integer;
   t text := '';
   c char(1);
   /*
    * 0 means unquoted
    * 1 means quoted
    * 2 means quoted, and we just read a quote
    */
   q integer := 0;
BEGIN
   /* loop through the characters */
   FOR i IN 1..length(line) LOOP
      /* get i-th character */
      c := substring(line FROM i FOR 1);
      /* end of string is at an unquoted delimiter */
      IF c = delim_char AND q <> 1 THEN
         result := result || t;
         t := '';
         q := 0;
      ELSIF c = quote_char THEN
         CASE q
            WHEN 0 THEN
               q := 1;
            WHEN 1 THEN
               IF c = quote_char THEN
                  q := 2;
               ELSE
                  t := t || c;
               END IF;
            WHEN 2 THEN
               q := 1;
               t := t || quote_char;
         END CASE;
      ELSE
         IF q = 2 THEN
            q := 0;
         END IF;
         t := t || c;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
   /* add the last string */
   result := result || t;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAble!   Hum... This algorithm will work with any CSV case? even simple algorith as [this perl one](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch01_21.htm) use regular expression... I was trying to use `regexp_matches()` but need to adapt `?:^|,)(?=[^"]|(")?)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)` to POSIX...

Comment: It should work for everything, unless I made a programming error. Sometimes it is simpler to write a state machine than to specify the grammar.